# Switching from landscape to portrait produces NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm making an app that displays events in a list. Each event has a custom layout (with BaseAdapter). If i'm using my phone in either only portrait or only landscape its ok, but if i'm on the list and rotate my phone to change the orientation the BaseAdapter produces a `NullPointerException`. Here is the code:

```
public class ShowListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity a;
    private List<Map<String, String>> monthList;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ShowListAdapter(Activity act, List<Map<String, String>> msc) {
        a = act;
        monthList = msc;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return monthList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;

        if (view == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        /* Some random code that formats the view goes here */

        return v;
    }
}
```

The error is thrown at `getCount()`, because it (i assume) can not find the list variable       `monthList`.

This class is used in a ListFragment class

```
public class ListForMonth extends ListFragment {
    List<Map<String, String>> eventListLoc;

    public ListForMonth() {}

    public ListForMonth(int i) {
        eventListLoc = ShowHolder.eventList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setListAdapter(new ShowListAdapter(this.getActivity(), eventListLoc));
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

The ShowHolder class has a single static variable that is "generated" in the splash screen of the application.

The main `Activity` has multiple tabs, each it's own `ListFragment`. The only important part of the code in there is this, i guess:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new ListForMonth(position);
}
```

Why does the code throw this error? And how can i fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Logcat: https://pastebin.com/Bv63a06A

Comment: posted answer check it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the problem is in this lines..

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
return new ListForMonth(position);
}
```

when ever the orientation changes Android calls the fragmnet with the default constructor..at that time your List> eventListLoc data is null..thats why it is giving NPE..

To avoid this..Change your fragment code like thiss..

```
public class ListForMonth extends ListFragment {
List<Map<String, String>> eventListLoc;
private int i;

public ListForMonth() {
}

public ListForMonth(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        i = savedInstanceState.getInt("POSITION");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    eventListLoc = ShowHolder.eventList.get(i);
    setListAdapter(new ShowListAdapter(this.getActivity(), eventListLoc));
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("POSITION", i);
}
}
```

Comment: Oh nice, didnt know about getInt and putInt. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Watch out because when you switch from landscape to portrait or from portrait to landscape, the activity restarts. So override the `onResume()` method and handle the screen orientation.